# Is there a word to describe someone who creates many different things?

Tags: word-choice, nouns

Say I wrote books, made video games, created films and cartoons; is there a noun to describe someone who creates a multitude of things like the ones previously mentioned? "Creator" sounds cryptic, "auteur" I think applies more to film? Having to say "author, game maker, filmmaker, etc" is redundant to me. Any help? Thanks

Comment: If your accomplishments were in widely different fields, you might consider the term [*renaissance man*](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renaissance_man). The gender-specificity is historical (no pun intended), and unfortunately *polymath*, also mentioned in the link, is more suggestive of personal ability than of accomplishments. However, I'm not sure that this term would be as appropriate where the fields are as closely aligned as the examples you cite.

Comment: Are you looking for a word such that you can say, “This is my friend John. He is a *frathegimist*. “ And I would be able to say, “Wow! You are an author, gamemaker, and filmmaker? That’s amazing!”  Or do you just want to say that John is multi-talented and then go on to enumerate those talents?

Comment: You might consider "profligate creator".  It's been used to describe God, Jimi Hendrix, and several others.

Comment: Leonardo da Vinci.

Answer (score 3):

Multimedia artist.  Unfortunately, enough college dropouts that can do basic color adjustments with Photoshop call themselves this so that the phrase has become rather cliche and empty.  You could be more demonstrably original with your own phrase: artist of eclectic media.  ?

Answer (score 1):

Multi-talented creator. One who creates in many fields, has 'many talents'.

Answer (score 1):

Polymath

One schooled in many areas.

polymath pŏl′ē-măth″►
n.  A person of great or varied learning.
n.  A person of various learning. Also polymathist.
n.  A person with extraordinarily broad and comprehensive knowledge.
More at Wordnik  from The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, 5th Edition.

Answer (score 0):

Not a single word, but two terms that come to mind are "jack of all trades" or "renaissance man."

If you want to make it specific, you could modify it slightly, to something like a "digital jack of all trades", or a "multimedia renaissance man", etc.