# Single word for multiskilled on different programming platforms

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, synonyms

I was just wondering if there's a word for a **multi skilled**/**multi talented** for a Web Designer, Web Developer and a Graphic Artist? Currently if you know everything on Software Development you will be called as a ***full-stack*** developer but that is only for Software Development. I'm trying to pick if its better to call it as a ***polymath*** or a ***virtuoso***  but i don't know if what is more better than the two of them.

Thank you guys in advance!!!

Comment: If there is a word that's spot on, it's almost certainly too jargonistic for a site devoted to standard usage. If not, candidates will be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Hi blake, check out this other similar question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/541891/is-there-a-word-for-a-full-stack-artist. You can use the search bar at the top to find similar questions before posting a new one. Welcome to ELU, cheers!